# Associate Adwords info with Contacts / Conversions on my website

Tags: php, analytics, google-ads-api, sem

My company run ads on Adwords for quite a while now.

We provide a special kind of Construction Services.

Since our solution is very complex, some people dont quite understand what we are offering but convert into a contact anyway. This happens because:

1 - They dont read the FAQ, neither the website content.
2 - They are just collecting quotes for a service they need, and just Copy + Paste their question on our Contact Form.
3 - Our service name is very hard to target correctly since the keyword is kind of "open to interpretation" and has a bunch of meanings.

I could exemplify with the keyword but i dont know the exact translation to english.

Anyway, we receive a bunch of Contacts. I can track conversions on AdWords and Analytics, i can see wich campaings, keywords, placements, etc are perfoming well, but here is what i really need:

**I need to know where THAT GUY that wrote that stupid question came from.**

I need to be able to associate AdWords data with the E-mails i receive trough the Contact Form.

I need to be able to, at the end of the month, collect those 1.000 contacts from my CRM wich are classified as "bad contact" and check where they came from. I could for instance find out that a specific placement in Display Network simply suck, i get conversions, but those  conversions are bad. Or maybe a specific keyword simply dont work, people always mistake that for something else.

I need to be able to look at this very good contact that came in and trace it back to exactly what campaign originated it, what keyword, what search term, etc.

At my disposal i have, of course, AdWords resources - i looked everywhere i could not find how to do it with Adwords only.

I also have a CodeIgniter / PHP Website. Maybe there is a way to read AdWords / Analytics cookies.

I also have knoledge to mess up with the Adwords API, in case that helps.

Any help from you guys is welcome.

**Sorry for my english - not my first language.**

Best regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

You might try using `eCommerce` module for analytics. Every time when the conversion is performed, create a new `product` and fill the fields (`SKU`, `Price`, `Order ID`, etc.) with data you need to identify contact